# Not able to change width and height of ionic modal page

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I'm trying to change width and height of ionic modal but not able to succeed.

In component file:

```
this.modalCtrl.create('DataCustomizerModalPage', {my data}, {cssClass: "my-modal"});
```

In scss file:

```
.my-modal{ width:1709.19px; height: 950px; }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hei Sai, please share you scss file exactly as it is. I think this is fixable

Comment: Hi Segrey. Thanks for your reply. i only have this code in my scss.   .my-modal .modal-wrapper{  
           width: 854px; 
           height: 550px; 
        }

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the `modal-wrapper` class to the selector. Your SCSS code in app.scss could look like this:

```
.my-modal .modal-wrapper{ width:1709.19px; height: 950px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply phonolog. but it didn't work for me. I just need to change default modal width and height.

Comment: Have you added the scss to your app.scss?

Comment: yes. i tried added it in app.scss and components scss file but neither of them worked.